# Deserialize json twitter string into object

Tags: c#, json, twitter

using the url below i am trying to pull the followers that a particular screen name has which is working fine. when i try deserialize the code into a ojbect i get the error message below any ideas why this would be. I have also put the code for the for the Json type.. I would like to get the Location filed. i have released that the users is an object itself. so can i get an example that will let me Desalinize  the initial object anf then the object within.

URL = `"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?&screen_name="will insert here "`

Deserialize into objec code

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(FollowerData)
```

Json type code

```
public class Follower
{

[JsonProperty("created_at")]
public string CreatedAt { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("id")]
public string Id { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("id_str")]
public string IdStr { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("name")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("screen_name")]
public string ScreenName { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("location")]
public bool Location { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("description")]
public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

Error Message

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g.
>   {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OAuthTwitterWrapper.JsonTypes.FollowerUsers]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'users', line 1, position
>   9."}

Json String Examplt

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 219566993,
            "id_str": "219566993",
            "name": "belenastorgano",
            "screen_name": "anna_belenn_",
            "location": "CapitalFederal, Argentina",
            "description": "Mesientonomade, todav\\u00edanotengounlugarfijodondevivir.-",
            "url": null,
            "entities": {
                "description": {
                    "urls": []
                }
            },
            "protected": true,
            "followers_count": 44,
            "friends_count": 64,
            "listed_count": 0,
            "created_at": "ThuNov2506: 28: 12+00002010",
            "favourites_count": 1,
            "utc_offset": -10800,
            "time_zone": "BuenosAires",
            "geo_enabled": true,
            "verified": false,
            "statuses_count": 207,
            "lang": "es",
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "is_translator": false,
            "profile_background_color": "599E92",
            "profile_background_image_url": "http: \\/\\/a0.twimg.com\\/images\\/themes\\/theme18\\/bg.gif",
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https: \\/\\/si0.twimg.com\\/images\\/themes\\/theme18\\/bg.gif",
            "profile_background_tile": false,
            "profile_image_url": "http: \\/\\/a0.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/378800000326157070\\/e91b8fd8e12eda0a7fa350dcd286c56a_normal.jpeg",
            "profile_image_url_https": "https: \\/\\/si0.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/378800000326157070\\/e91b8fd8e12eda0a7fa350dcd286c56a_normal.jpeg",
            "profile_link_color": "E05365",
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "EEEEEE",
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "F6F6F6",
            "profile_text_color": "333333",
            "profile_use_background_image": true,
            "default_profile": false,
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "following": null,
            "follow_request_sent": null,
            "notifications": null
        }
    ],
    "next_cursor": 1443863551966642400,
    "next_cursor_str": "1443863551966642309",
    "previous_cursor": 0,
    "previous_cursor_str": "0"
}
```

Comment: Put a sample json string into this site: http://json2csharp.com/
See if the class structure matches.

Comment: it doent work on that site. and and i am creating my own json types

Comment: *`it doent work on that site. and and i am creating my own json types`* It think you don't know what you are doing. I pasted your sample json to that site and used the classes it created like **`var followerData=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json); Console.WriteLine(followerData.users[0].location);`**. **tada**. It worked.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the only field i need is the location in the user table

You don't need any class to get a few fields from your json. Just make use of `dynamic`

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); 
Console.WriteLine(dynObj.users[0].location);
```

Comment: this works, but as i will be pulling multiple user data at once how would i chnage so that it gets all

Comment: What is hard in `foreach(var user in dynObj.users)`?

Comment: @SimonPatel Why not? just post a sample json and I will show you it will indeed work. BTW: *This method* is not much different than deserialzing to a concerete class, just uses *dynamic*.

Answer (score 1):

```
Follower[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Follower[]>(FollowerData);
```

And if you wish it to be a `List<Follower>` then you can call `.ToList()` (you need `using System.Linq;`).

---

```
using System.Linq;

List<Follower> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Follower[]>(FollowerData).ToList();
```

Or you could pass the array to the list (no linq):

```
List<Follower> result = new List<Follower>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Follower[]>(FollowerData));
```

Comment: what do u mean by the second part can u show me what u mean.. dont quite undertstand,

Comment: In that case I would like to see an example of `FollowerData`

Comment: My code isn't wrong, but it can be that your `Follower` class doesn't match the json.

Comment: is that the answer after i sent you the onbject

Comment: no it is not, I am currently at work with not the most time. Ill get back to you asap.

Comment: the only field i need is the location in the user table.

Answer (score 0):

According to your JSON the data you want to retrieve is IN a JSON array (the item with the user data is between right brackets - the '"users" : [ ] part ')

So to get this to parse correctly, you have to create another class which contains an array of Follower objects, and add a `JsonProperty("users")` attribute to this array. Then you can deserialize your JSON correctly to that class.

To clarify:

The container class:

```
public class FollowerContainer
{
   [JsonProperty("users")]
   public Follower[] Followers { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization:

`var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof (FollowerCollection));`

You can use then `result.Followers` to get access to your data.